# payload in requestMessage is modifying with response object in Outbound-gateway request

Tags: spring-integration

```
<channel id="shipTypeInfo" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="shipInfoGateway"
    request-channel="shipTypeInfo"
    url="${oms.config.service.provider}omsconfig/shiptype?shipTypeId={shipTypeId}"
    http-method="GET" reply-channel="shipTypeInfo"
    extract-request-payload="false" 
    expected-response-type="com.abc.xyz.mac.integration.audit.domain.someInfo">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="shipTypeId"
        expression="payload" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>`
```

On the call of shipTypeGateway in my service with "integer" input, integer value is coming in payload and calling external service properly, but i got HTTP: 415 error.

**When i debug**, i have observed: HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(Message requestMessage) is calling 2 times.

**First time**, payload is going with integer as expected and again is calling second time internally, but **2nd** time payload is modified with response object(ShipInfo), that why it is giving response **HTTP: 415 error**.

How to make 2nd time payload also should go with integer.

Any help can be appreciated.

Note : Spring-Integration 4.1.6 using currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, having `request-channel="shipTypeInfo" reply-channel="shipTypeInfo"` as a loop, what are you going to do for the third call, after we reach the successful for the second one ?

So, you have to re-design your logic and introduce some `router`/`filter` after that `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` to identify if you need the second call or already no. In addition there in the downstream you will be able to `transform` your `ShipInfo` to integer back for the second call.

Anyway I can't help you to overcome the original question with the current solution. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Now i use different channels for request and response, we are getting response. Thanks it is working.